# disable .hover() function for small screens jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can i please get some help with jQuery hover function. My problem is I m trying to have a slieUp and slideDown function called on the hover of the div but i want to disable this effect for smaller screen i.e when screen is re-sized. If i re-size the screen i need to refresh the page for the change to take place. Also tried to use the `$(window).resize` instead of `$(document).ready` but it wont work until i re-size the window

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   if ($(window).width() > 990 ) {   
      $('.block_holder').hover(

       function(){
            $(this).find('.top_half').slideDown(450);
          },

          function(){
              $(this).find('.top_half').slideUp(450);
          }
  );
 } 

});
```

Comment: try moving that if($(window).width()... - condition down by one line. inside the hover ;)

Comment: @ManuelRicharz Surely you mean *down* by *two lines*? It would need to go inside of each of the functions passed to `.hover()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sry, yes, down. good morning. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a resize event handler like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(window).resize(function () {
         if ($(window).width() > 990) {
             $('.block_holder').on('mouseenter.large', function () {
                 $(this).find('.top_half').slideDown(450);
             }).on('mouseleave.large', function () {
                 $(this).find('.top_half').slideUp(450);
             });
         } else {
             $('.block_holder').off('mouseenter.large mouseleave.large');
         }
     }).resize(); //to initialize the value
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nDVsf/)

Comment: I'm not sure which would be more efficient. Checking the width inside of the `hover` handler(s) and not having to potentially bind/unbind event handlers, or doing it this way. This would definitely work though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think the answer might lie in how often the resize event occurs vs the hover event?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Definitely. Checking the width should be less overhead than binding/unbinding the events, but it's potentially going to happen a lot more often. There's probably not going to be any performance issues with either approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to bind the function on resize event:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
...your code goes here...
}
```

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
window.onresize = function(event) {

  if ($(window).width() > 990 ) {   
  $('.block_holder').hover(
      function(){
        $(this).find('.top_half').slideDown(450);
       },

      function(){
          $(this).find('.top_half').slideUp(450);
      }
   );
  } 
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Furquan, thanks for the reply. If i bind the function to the resize event the function wont work until i re-size the window. I want it to work even after the page is loaded.

Comment: Oh yes.. I added the document.ready event. hope now it satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Still it wont work until i re-size the window as the event is bind to window re-size. Check out the answer by Arun P Johny that code works great.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you writing the code that sets the dom in separate function. And then you can call it on every window.resize.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    setblockholder();
});
```

This way it is ensured that functionality of slideup/slidedown does not brake on window resize.