# off mouse hover function not working?

Tags: jquery

i want to disable mouseover and mouseleave option when screen size is less that 768.every thing seems fine but the code is not working.any suggestion ?? n i want only mouse hover option to work when screen size is greater than 768.

myscript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        if ($(window).width() > 768) 
        {
                    $('.dropdown').mouseover(function()
                    {
                        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).next('.dropdown-menu').show();
                    }).mouseout(function()
                    {
                        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).next('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                    });
        }
                else 
                {
                    $('.dropdown').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
                }
          $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() 
            {
                if ($(this).next('.dropdown-menu').is(':visible')) 
                {
                    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
                }
            });
    });

    $(window).resize(function()
    {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) 
        {
                    $('.dropdown').mouseover(function()
                    {
                        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).next('.dropdown-menu').show();
                    }).mouseout(function()
                    {
                        $('.dropdown-toggle', this).next('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                    });
        }
                else 
                {
                    $('.dropdown').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
                }
          $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() 
            {
                if ($(this).next('.dropdown-menu').is(':visible')) 
                {
                    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: you should use CSS media queries for that. Regarding your code, your logic is wrong, you are nesting events here. You should just check for `$(window).width()` (or better using `window.matchMedia()`) inside mouseover/mouseout events. BTW, using `mouseenter` would be more relevant i guess

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427162/disable-hover-function-for-small-screens-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code if it helps you out :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').mouseover(function() {
        dropDownToggleShowHide(this, false);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        dropDownToggleShowHide(this, true);
    });
    $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        if ($(this).next('.dropdown-menu').is(':visible')) {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
});



function dropDownToggleShowHide(el, hide){
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        return;
    }
    if(hide){
        $('.dropdown-toggle', el).next('.dropdown-menu').hide();    
    }
    else{
        $('.dropdown-toggle', el).next('.dropdown-menu').show();
    }
}
```